# Flutter update state with Inherited Widget

Tags: flutter

I have state full widget with Inherited Widget, i pass most of my data to the Inherited Widget
because i have children and grandchildren so it is more comfortable, my problem is when i update the state, the children is not updated accordingly, there is something that can fix that of i most pass props to make theme update.

```
class GameScreenData extends InheritedWidget {
  const GameScreenData(
      {this.votes,
      this.canVote,
      this.vote,
      this.fixture,
      this.localTeamLastFixtures,
      this.visitorTeamLastFixtures,
      this.odds,
      this.bookmakersInfo,
      Key key,
      this.child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  final Fixture fixture;
  final List localTeamLastFixtures, visitorTeamLastFixtures;
  final dynamic votes;
  final bool canVote;
  final Odd odds;
  final String bookmakersInfo;

  final Widget child;
  final Function vote;

  static GameScreenData of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<GameScreenData>();
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(GameScreenData oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int fixtureExternalId;
  final Advertisement advertisement;
  GameScreen({Key key, this.fixtureExternalId, this.advertisement}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  Fixture fixture;
  List localTeamLastFixtures, visitorTeamLastFixtures;
  dynamic votes;
  bool canVote;
  Odd odds;
  String bookmakersInfo;
  Future initScreen;

  Future setFIxture(externalId) async {
    final response = await locator<FixturesService>().getLiveFixtureByExternalId(externalId);

    setState(() {
      fixture = Fixture.fromMap(response["fixture"]);
      localTeamLastFixtures = response["localTeamLastFixtures"];
      visitorTeamLastFixtures = response["visitorTeamLastFixtures"];
      odds = Odd.fromMap(response["odds"]);
      bookmakersInfo = response["bookmakersInfo"];
      votes = response["votesData"]["votes"];
      canVote = response["votesData"]["canVote"];

      if (votes.length == 0) {
        votes = {"1": 0, "x": 0, "2": 0};
      }
    });

    return true;
  }

  vote(type) {
    setState(() {
      if (canVote) {
        var newVotes = votes;
        newVotes[type]++;
        votes = newVotes;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 1), () {
          if (mounted) {
            votes[type]--;
          }
        });

        canVote = false;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initScreen = setFIxture(widget.fixtureExternalId);
    TimerUtils.addTimer(FreeTimer(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 30),
      callback: () {
        setFIxture(widget.fixtureExternalId);
        print('fetch game screen every 30 seconds');
      },
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget advertisementWidget = Container();
    final League currentLeague = fixture != null ? Provider.of<LeaguesProvider>(context).getById(fixture.league["externalId"]) : null;

    if (widget.advertisement != null) {
      advertisementWidget = AdvertismentWidget(advertisement: widget.advertisement);
    }

    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: initScreen,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Loader();

            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return LoadError(error: snapshot.error);
              } else {
                return GameScreenData(
                  fixture: fixture,
                  localTeamLastFixtures: localTeamLastFixtures,
                  visitorTeamLastFixtures: visitorTeamLastFixtures,
                  votes: votes,
                  canVote: canVote,
                  odds: odds,
                  bookmakersInfo: bookmakersInfo,
                  vote: vote,
                  child: Column(
```

Comment: Any reason to not use state management like provider or any other ?

Comment: because providers are for cases i want to pass data through all the app and screens, and this case is for the same screen so i thought it isn't the right solution

Comment: Who told you this rule ?

Comment: google lol so you tell me providers are for every case that i pass prop more than 2/3 level?